# Testcafe: How to achieve ctrl+ mouse wheel action

Tags: testing, testcafe

I want to simulate the ctrl+ mouse wheel action in testcafe.

To verify that canvas resizes in response to this.

The following code not take effect,and webpage throw a js error.

```
test.only("temp", async t => {
    await t.dispatchEvent(Selector("#tempCanvas"),"wheel",{
        deltaY: -100,
        ctrlKey: true,
    })
})
```

[image]

In the browser, it's ok if I execute the following code.

```
var dom=document.getElementById("tempCanvas")
var event = new WheelEvent('wheel', {
    deltaY: -100,
    ctrlKey: true
});
dom.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Comment: Please share a simple page where the error is reproduced in your test.